# Why are most down-votes because of personal dislike here?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question which has received 3 down-votes.

Well, a good question is a question which is clear and well-written.

My question was also clear.

A post that should be down-voted is a post that is not clear and/or is off-topic.

So the down-votes it has received just shows the biased and hateful nature of this site and its inhabitants. Down-voting just because Muslims can't bear criticism.

**If a religious site don't open its arms to questions like this (or any doubtful questions disbelieving Islam) it's better that site not exist at all!**

One of the ways for a religion to attract others is to at least smile and answer questions from *heretics* instead of hate them.

As you can see my account is pending deletion. Not just the reaction to my question triggered me to do this. But also seeing the number of not-useful questions like seeking if a particular thing is haraam or halaal, or seeing how many hate there is against non-Muslims triggered me to do this too.

Christiany site is not very good too, but better!

The black hand of new contributors both shows hello and goodbye I think!

Answer (score 1):

Voting is anonymous and people can and do downvote for any number of reasons.

The fact that you automatically assume it's because of bias and hatred rather than because of any inherent problems with your questions says far more about you than it does about our community.

As does deleting your account simply for not being immediately welcomed with open arms after contributing barely anything to the site.

Comment: Well, I didn't say voting isn't anonymous.

Comment: At least a response. Thanks!

Comment: @SnackExchange Yet even without knowing their names, you still claim to know the minds of everyone who downvotes. That's just arrogance.

Comment: It's not hard to think about the reason for down-voting my question. Questions like this are highly received and appreciated in places like Al-Azhar university which is a great place of Islamic experts. Because questions like this are good and challenging. Even it can be asked in religious debates to be answered by experts.

Comment: @SnackExchange And if you'd [bothered to search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge-of-the-quran), you probably would've found it asked and answered multiple times on this site. We tend to downvote "challenging" questions when they're just the same questions that non-Muslims have been asking for years just to try to trip up Muslims. We've heard them all.

Comment: They might be welcome in Islamic debates, but we decided early on that we _are not_ and _will not be_ just another debate site. There's plenty of site for that out there already, and they're doing a pretty terrible job at actually making knowledge on Islam easy to find through walls of confusing rhetoric and questionable arguments.

Comment: *We tend to downvote "challenging" questions when they're just the same questions that non-Muslims have been asking for years just to try to trip up Muslims*. I looked at those challenging questions. Non of them were the same with my specific question! Also, using "if you'd bothered to search" isn't nice in StackExchange. You should know this as a moderator.

Comment: Also, those "challenging" questions you gave its link to me, doesn't have any CHALLENGING questions at all. They are just questions blaming disbelievers and proving the Quran is unchallengable! No one has posted a daring question just like mine.

Comment: And when I tried to post a new question when I had received two downvotes it said **you can't post another question for several days**! I think a few Stack Exchange sites (if any) are like this! Restricting a user just for asking **one** question which isn't received very well? A new user should be given time to get better. This behavior is really killing a new contributor's enthusiasm and motivation! I can't post a question even now! On Math site I got restricted after posting **four** bad questions. On Astronomy, I'm doing well.